# SSIS Packages unable to load due to XML issues

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2017

I created an SSIS Package that collects data from a local machine and stores it as a new table into the new server. The package runs successfully when I invoke it but the SQL Server Agent cant run it. I granted the server access to the local machine but it still refuses. One of the suggestions I got was that I need to give the server access to my package which I shared with the server but i'm still getting the same results. how can I solve this? Please answer with step by step instructions since this is my first SSIS package that i am trying to schedule.

[image: See Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: could you please provide screenshots of your current shedule configuration?

Comment: How do I add a picture here?

Comment: There should be an icon on the right side of "{ }" displaying something like a mountain. Click it and you will be prompted to drag and drop your picture.

Comment: Done I added the screenshot. The schedule there was just for testing

Comment: OK and screenshot of your Job / Jobstep configuration as well please

Comment: By the way: what do you mean with you "granted acces to the local machine"? Didn't you deploy the package / solution?

Comment: I gave the server access to read my SSIS Package since the package is stored on my local machine. The data I'm retrieving is sitting on another local machine. So we have my local machine, the server and the other machine I'm retrieving from.

Comment: I would say the problem is the following: Your job tries to execute a package on the server. Since you provided a path "c:\Users\..." it searches for this path on the server... either you copy your package to the corresponding destination or (and this is more native I guess...) you create a corresponding folder in the SSIS Catalog and deploy your package / solution to this location. Afterwards modify your job in order to use this new location.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157282/discussion-between-otshepeng-ditshego-and-tyron78).

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Local machine implies local to where the process is being run.  When you run the package on your desktop, it is the local machine. When your server tries to run the package, the server is the local machine.

A drive based file path will be resolved by the server at run time, asking the server to look in its C:\Users\DitsheOO..... path for the package.   If that path/package doesn't exist, the job\package will fail.

You need to publish the package to the server's local drive (it will not be in your desktop's local drive) and update the SQL Server Agent job definition.

Or preferably, use a UNC path (e.g. \servername\servershare\folderpath...\packagepath.dtsx) that can be accessed by any device with permission to the folder.